# Gaussian Elimination Elements $a^{(r)}_{ij}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, numerical-linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. We apply GE to it. Prove that:

$\begin{align}
a^{(r)}_{ij}&=   a^{(r)}_{ij}=\frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r & i \\
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r & j 
\end{pmatrix}}{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r
\end{pmatrix}} 
\end{align}$

where $A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r
\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r  \\
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r  
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r & i \\
    1 & 2 &\cdots & r & j 
\end{pmatrix}=det\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} &... & a_{1j} \\
. & & &. \\
. & & & .\\
. & & &.\\
a_{i1} & a_{i2} &... &a_{ij} \end{pmatrix} $

My work so far:
I have shown that the hypothesis is true for $r=1$ using the formula $$a^{(1)}_{ij}=a_{ij}-\frac{a_{i1}}{a_{11}}a_{1j}$$ I try to prove the rest using induction. Suppose there is a $r=p$ such that

\begin{align}
    a^{(p)}_{ij}=\frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & p & i \\
    1 & 2 &\cdots & p & j 
\end{pmatrix}}{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 &\cdots & p
\end{pmatrix}} 
\end{align}
Then for $r=p+1$, using  $a_{ij}^{(p+1)} = a^{(p)}_{ij}-\frac{a^{(p)}_{ip+1}}{a^{(p)}_{p+1p+1}}a^{(p)}_{p+1j}$ I concluded to:

\begin{align}
a^{(p+1)}&= \frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cdots & p & i\\
    1 & \cdots & p & j
\end{pmatrix}}{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &\cdots &p \\
    1 &\cdots &p
\end{pmatrix}} -\frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cdots & p & i \\
    1 & \cdots & p & p+1
\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & \cdots &p &p+1 \\
    1 &\cdots &p &j
\end{pmatrix}}{A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &\cdots &p \\
    1 &\cdots &p
\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}
    1 &\cdots &p & p+1 \\
    1 & \cdots &p &p+1
\end{pmatrix}}
\end{align}
How can I proceed?

Comment: You need some assumptions in the particular GE process used to know that $A(1\cdots r)\ne0$. With those assumptions, you should see based on the form of the partially reduced matrix that $A(1\cdots r)$ is just the product of the first $r$ diagonal elements, and when you adjoin row $i$ and column $j$ to the minor, you're just multiplying by the additional single element $a^{(r)}_{ij}$.

Comment: @blargoner I didnt understand. Can you write it with equation please? My english is not so good

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment: assuming that $A(1\cdots k)\ne0$ for all $1\le k\le p$ for some $p\le n-1$, after the $p$-th reduction step the partially reduced matrix looks like
$$G_p=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1p}&a_{1,p+1}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
&a^{(1)}_{22}&\cdots&a^{(1)}_{2p}&a^{(1)}_{2,p+1}&\cdots&a^{(1)}_{2n}\\
&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&&a^{(p-1)}_{pp}&a^{(p-1)}_{p,p+1}&\cdots&a^{(p-1)}_{pn}\\
&&&&a^{(p)}_{p+1,p+1}&\cdots&a^{(p)}_{p+1,n}\\
&&&&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&&&a^{(p)}_{n,p+1}&\cdots&a^{(p)}_{nn}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Therefore since minors from $A$ and $G_p$ among the first rows are equal,
$$A(1\cdots p)=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1p}\\
&a^{(1)}_{22}&\cdots&a^{(1)}_{2p}\\
&&\ddots&\vdots\\
&&&a^{(p-1)}_{pp}\\
\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}a^{(1)}_{22}\cdots a^{(p-1)}_{pp}\ne0$$
and for $p+1\le i,j\le n$,
$$A\begin{pmatrix}
1&\cdots&p&i\\
1&\cdots&p&j
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1p}&a_{1j}\\
&a^{(1)}_{22}&\cdots&a^{(1)}_{2p}&a^{(1)}_{2j}\\
&&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
&&&a^{(p-1)}_{pp}&a^{(p-1)}_{pj}\\
&&&&a^{(p)}_{ij}
\end{vmatrix}=a_{11}a^{(1)}_{22}\cdots a^{(p-1)}_{pp}a^{(p)}_{ij}=A(1\cdots p)\,a^{(p)}_{ij}$$
so
$$a^{(p)}_{ij}=\frac{A\begin{pmatrix}
1&\cdots&p&i\\
1&\cdots&p&j
\end{pmatrix}}{A(1\cdots p)}$$